# XML format switch to the JSON format in WSO2

Tags: json, xml, wso2, esb

I have a response like this:

```
Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><jsonObject><Number>UUI006</Number><Number>UURR007</Number><Number>UUR004</Number></jsonObject></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

My schema and output of the JSON format remark as below.

Method1

Schema:

```
 <property expression="$body/*" name="test" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
 <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
     <format>
        <jsonObject>       
            <code>$1</code>
        </jsonObject>
     </format>
     <args>                           
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:test"/>
     </args>
  </payloadFactory>
  <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
```

Output:

```
 {
   "code": {
            "number": [
                "UUI006",
                "UURR007",
                "UUR004"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Method2

Schema:

```
 <property expression="json-eval($.number)" name="test" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
 <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
     <format>
        <jsonObject>       
            <code>$1</code>
        </jsonObject>
     </format>
     <args>                           
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:test"/>
     </args>
  </payloadFactory>
  <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
```

Output:

```
{
    "code": "[\"UUI006\",\"UURR007\",\"UUR004\"]"
}
```

But I need the JSON format like this, how can I do?

```
{
   "code": [ "UUI006", "UURR007", "UUR004" ]
}
```